# Grabbing tweets using PHP

Tags: php, twitter, web-crawler

I am trying to grab tweets from Twitter. What I have is a list of users which I would like to grab their tweets from and store them in my database. I would like to know if I am going to use Twitter API or is there any simple code for me to achieve this.

According to https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries#php there are five libraries in PHP. I would like to know which one is good for me to use?

Thanks everyone.

Comment: did you test one of them at least ? i mean what have you done so far ?

Comment: "Using the API" and "simple code" are not opposite choices.

Comment: Also, if your requirements are "grab a user's tweets", I'm *pretty sure* each of the libraries can do that.

Comment: I just followed the tutorial
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JWONayq1EKM
to grab a tweet from a specified user and I am not sure if it is better to use API though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Twitter it couldn't be simpler. Just `file_get_contents()` this URL: http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=USERNAME&count=10 and you'll get a JSON with USERNAME's 10 latest tweets.

```
$tweets = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=USERNAME&count=10'));

var_dump($tweets);
```

Comment: this doesn't work anymore

Comment: If you Google "Twitter API" you'll notice they've changed their URL.

Comment: Not just that. they deprecated all the non-authenticated API. you now have to authenticate before making any calls to API 1.1